# onSaveInstanceState() - only one passes

Tags: java, android, onsaveinstancestate

Update: including actual code

I am using ArrayList to fill a custom adapter and it works fine on orientation change etc.:

"onCreate"

```
myArrayList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(myListkey);
```

"onSaveInstanceState"

```
savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(myListkey, myArrayList);
```

and I can get it out fine

But.. I need to pass multiple variables and then it breaks, it looks like it´s only the one inserted last that I can get.

ex.1

"onCreate"

```
myNameString = savedInstanceState.getString(namekey);
myArrayList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(myListkey);
```

"onSaveInstanceState"

```
savedInstanceState.putString(listkey, myNameString);
savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(myListkey, myArrayList);
```

Here "myArrayList" is filled, but "myNameString" is null

---

ex. 2

"onCreate"

```
myArrayList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(listkey);
myNameString = savedInstanceState.getString(namekey);
```

"onSaveInstanceState"

```
savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(listkey, myArrayList);
savedInstanceState.putString(namekey, myNameString);
```

Here "myNameString" is filled, but "myArrayList" is null

---

original code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
_listName = savedInstanceState.getString(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.saved_instance_list_name));
_listItems = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.saved_instance_list_items_edit));
 }

 ... more code

 }


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState.putString(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.saved_instance_list_name), _listName);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.saved_instance_list_items_edit), _listItems);

}
```

Comment: `myNameString = savedInstanceState.getString(namekey);` AND `savedInstanceState.putString(listkey, myNameString);` do not match. You should use the same key for both.

Comment: In ex1..you are using different key to get the value which not yet put.
In ex2. You are using same key to put 2 different values.

Comment: @ZeroKat did you manage to make this work?

Comment: No not really. I created a paceble class which contains all the relevant data.